# share audio files with whatsapp in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed the SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin for file sharing.
I can share images and text, but not audio files.

```
//stringToBase64 function convert string to the base64
        var base64audio = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,' + stringToBase64('audio-file.mp3');  
        window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, 'www/files/audio-file.mp3', base64audio, null);
```

I tried this way, but whatsapp can not share this file.
Can you help me please?